Evaluate $\int^{\infty}_{0} \arctan\left({\frac{a^2}{x^2}}\right)\cos(bx)dx$
$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \arctan\left({\frac{a^2}{x^2}}\right)\cos(bx)dx$$
I was able to solve a special case of this integral using the Laplace transform:
$$I=\int^{\infty}_{0} \arctan\left({\frac{2}{x^2}}\right)\cos(bx)dx\overset{Ibp}{=}\frac{4}{b}\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{x\sin(bx)}{4+x^4}dx$$
Let :
$$J(b)=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x\sin(bx)}{4+x^4}dx$$
$$L(J(b))=\int^{\infty}_{0}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x\sin(bx)e^{-sb})}{4+x^4}dxdb=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x^2}{(4+x^4)(s^2+x^2)}dx=\frac{\pi}{4(1+(s+1)^2))}$$
therfore:
$$J(b)=\frac{\pi}{4}L^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{1+(s+1)^2}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}e^{-b}\sin(b)$$
therfore:
$$I=\frac{\pi}{b}e^{-b}\sin(b)$$
But in the general case, I have no idea, and need help.

If the special case you claim were right it'd be easy to generalize, but it's not. It should be $\frac{\pi\sin b}{be^{|b|}}$. I suggest editing your calculation into the question.

Assuming @J.G. is correct it would be useful for you to explain your incorrect derivation of $\pi e^{-2b}$ for the integral. Answerers would be able to 1. see where you went wrong and explain it to you, 2. after correcting that error explain how to generalize it. 3. It's entirely possible you might find the correct generalization on your own just by doing this.

As already observed by J.G., you special integral has the right result $\pi e^{-\vert b\vert}\frac{\sin(\vert b\vert)}{\vert b\vert}$.
I suggest to use a change of variable to use the integral that you already computed.
Let
$$ I(a,b):=\int_0^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)\cos(bx)dx.$$
We already know that $I(\sqrt{2},b)=\pi e^{-\vert b\vert}\frac{\sin(\vert b\vert)}{\vert b\vert}$.
Furthermore, if $a=0$, then the integral is zero. Hence, let us assume $a\neq 0$.
For the general case we use $y:=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\vert a\vert}x$. Then when $x\mapsto 0$ we have $y\mapsto 0$ and when $x\mapsto \infty$ then $y\mapsto\infty$, so that
$$I(a,b)=\frac{\vert a\vert}{\sqrt{2}}I\left(\sqrt{2},\frac{\vert a\vert b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\vert a\vert\pi e^{-\frac{\vert ab\vert}{\sqrt{2}}}\frac{\sin(\frac{\vert ab\vert}{\sqrt{2}})}{\vert ab\vert}=\pi e^{-\frac{\vert ab\vert}{\sqrt{2}}}\frac{\sin(\frac{\vert ab\vert}{\sqrt{2}})}{\vert b\vert}, \qquad a\in \mathbb R.$$

WLOG assume $a,b>0$. Sketch of a solution.

Integration by parts with $dv= \cos(bx)$. The boundary terms vanish.

The new integral is
$$\frac{2a^2}{b}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(bx)}{a^4+x^4}\,dx$$

Let $x=au$ and write $K=ab$:


$$=\frac{2}{b}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u\sin(Ku)}{1+u^4}\,du$$

This is amenable to the residue theorem; exercise.

